# Mongodb4.4 aggregation sorting random behaviour

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation query that i am running on mongo4.4 and getting weird sorting order . If the order of two document is same , getting random sorting order for those document having same sorting order . Ideally if sorting order is same then results should be sorted by natural order . Query is running fine on mongo3.6 .

```
db.getCollection('job').aggregate([
{"$match":{"$text":{"$search":"\"Cleaner\""}}},
{"$match":{"active":true}},
{"$match":{"status":"OPEN"}},
{"$project": 
{"id":1,"source":1,"feed":1,"cardType":1,"groupCategory":1,"isPremium":1,"premiumTillDate":1,"createdDate":1,"title":1,"featuredImageUrl":1,"companyName":1,"salaryType":1,"contractType":1,"jobDescription":1,"location":1,"scope":1,"microRole":1,"address":1,"minimumSalary":1,"hiringManagerName":1,"hiringManagerImageUrl":1,"createdBy":1,"perks":1,"showMapView":1,"distance":1,"startDate":1,"link":"$externalJobDetail.link","publishDateTime":"$externalJobDetail.publishDateTime","salaryDescription":"$externalJobDetail.salaryDescription","companyJobLogoURL":"$externalJobDetail.companyJobLogoURL","monetisation":"$monetisation.value","order":"$monetisation.value"}},
{"$sort":{"order":-1}},
        {"$skip":0},
        {"$limit":29}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `_id` field to the sort query to achieve a stable sort.

```
db.getCollection('job').aggregate(
   [
     // pipeline stages
     { $sort : { order : -1, _id: -1 } }
   ]
)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#behavior):

> If a stable sort is desired, include at least one field in your sort that contains exclusively unique values. The easiest way to guarantee this is to include the _id field in your sort query.